# Choice of lower bound of curve for PV work

Tags: thermodynamics

I am told that the area under the PV curve gives the magnitude of work done by a gas.

Let $V_i$ be the initial volume, $V_f$ be the final volume, and the pressure as a function of volume be given by $P=f(V)$. To my understanding, the work done is given by the area bounded by $x=V_i$, $x=V_f$, $P=F(v)$ and $y=0$.

[image]

[image]

Proceeding in the above stated manner, the work done comes out to be the sum of the areas of green and yellow region, but the answer stated neglects the yellow region.

Origin of Question : [JEE MAIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Entrance_Examination)

Here's the answer according to the official answer key released by the testing agency:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error comes from reading the graph: the crossing of the axes corresponds to the point (2,2) and not (0,0)

Comment: If that is correct, then we must be dealing with a thermodynamic cycle here, with the lower boundary of the cycle p = 2.  Otherwise, where we placed the lower boundary on the graph would not matter.

Comment: @ChetMiller but the question states that the inital state of gas is A and final state is C, which does not form a thermodynamic cycle.

Comment: I still think that implicitly, it is necessary to add a point D (2,2) and that the gas describes the cycle ABCDA otherwise we cannot effectively neglect the yellow region in the added image

Comment: I agree with Nicolases'.   And, if the yellow area is included, then the work is 64.

Comment: @ChetMiller, please check the recent edits.

Comment: @SuchetSaxena even the biggest can make mistakes! Nothing justifies the given value of $ \pu{48J} $ other than that of a cycle such as the one shown in the figure!

Comment: @Nicolas, seems like a huge error went unnoticed. Odd that nobody has picked it up even after a year.

Comment: I did not quite receive the closure I was looking for. If the answer truly is 64, then a test that has huge stakes got it wrong and nobody even rectified it.

Comment: I understand your disappointment but I do not see how they can find the advertised value